# GO : model ( or interface ) function with input of different types

Tags: go, revel

Right now I have a small application for calculating statistics with a parallel algorithms. 
Now I've got a problem with expanding some part of functionality. I'll try to explain shortly.
App is build on revel framework. One of the actions of "stat" controller takes incoming POST json. Parses it. And generates two channels (goroutines) for tasks and results. All that works like a charm. But I have troubles with models. I wrote code to be able to expand models amount linearly, but for this moment there was only one in work.

And not all of methods are adopted for this expanding.

In some part of code I have this :

```
for t := range in {
        for sourceName, charts := range t.Request.Charts {

            var cacheData []byte
            var deserializedData models.StatModel

            //determine the model type
            switch sourceName {
            case "noagg":
                deserializedData = new(models.NoaggModel)
            case "acsi":
                deserializedData = new(models.AcsiModel)
            }

            cache_err := cache.Get(string(string(sourceName) + "_" + string(t.Date)), &cacheData);
            if cache_err != nil {
                panic("the cache is empty")
            }

            marshal_error := json.Unmarshal([]byte(cacheData), &deserializedData)
            if marshal_error == nil {

            }

            deserializedData.FilterData(t.Request.Filters)

            deserializedData.ClusterData(t.Request.Filters)

            w := Work{}
            for _, chart := range charts {
                countedData := ChartElements{}

                if marshal_error == nil {
                    countedData = deserializedData.CountDataForChart(string(chart.Name))
                }else {
                    panic("some is bad")
                }

                w.Name, w.Data = chart.Name, countedData
                out <- w
            }
        }
    }
```

Noagg model and Asci model are implementing the same interface of the "stat" model :

```
type StatModel interface {
    FilterData(Filter)
    ClusterData(Filter)
    CountDataForChart(string)[]ChartElement
    GroupByTreeGroups(Filter)[]OrgPack
}
```

But now I have to add some new models with the same interface, but there is code, that I can't expand . I can't remember how to do this..

```
func statCount(model NoaggRow, f func(NoaggRow) float64) float64 {
    countedStat := f(model)
    return countedStat
}

func Count(model NoaggRow, name string) float64{

    m := map[string]func(NoaggRow) float64 {
        "HOLD" : HOLD,
        "INB"  : INB,
        "AHT"  : AHT,
        "RING" : RING,
        "TALK" : TALK,
        "ACW"  : ACW,
        "OCC"  : OCC,
    }
    countedStat := statCount(model, m[name])
    return countedStat
}
```

The same methods I need for ASCI model. For AcsiRow instead of NoaggRow. How to make this input params types dynamic or how to make methods common for all models. Only array and names of "map[string]func(......Row)"  would differ in this place. Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions in the map (that is, `HOLD()`, `INB()`, etc) do not need more access to the models than the StatModel interface provides, then your requirement should be possible by changing these functions to receive a StatModel instead of a NoaggRow:

```
func HOLD(s StatModel) float64 {
    ...
}
```

Then the AcsiRow functions that you want to add can have the same signature, and statCount and Count can be rewritten as follows:

```
func statCount(model StatModel, f func(StatModel) float64) float64 {
    countedStat := f(model)
    return countedStat
}

func Count(model StatModel, name string) float64 {
    m := map[string]func(StatModel) float64 {
        "HOLD" : HOLD,
        "INB"  : INB,
        "AHT"  : AHT,
        "RING" : RING,
        "TALK" : TALK,
        "ACW"  : ACW,
        "OCC"  : OCC,
        // Map AcsiModel functions here, let's call them ACSIn here
        // (you mentioned that the names would be different, so
        // I assume they don't get in the way of the functions
        // above):
        "ACSI1": ACSI1,
        "ACSI2": ACSI2,
        "ACSI3": ACSI3,
    }
    countedStat := statCount(model, m[name])
    return countedStat
}
```

Disclaimer: This is just an idea that is based on what I can see in the post. I know nothing about Revel and maybe I thus might have missed some important detail that is induced by the Revel context that would prevent implementing this approach.

**Update** based on the comment:

Use [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to enable the `HOLD`, `OCC`, etc. functions to access struct specific attributes, like so:

```
func HOLD (s StatModel) float64 {
    noagg, ok := s.(NoaggRow) // typecast from StateModel to NoaggRow
    if !ok {
        // Looks like the caller did not pass a matching model/name pair into Count().
        // Error handling...
    }
    attr := noagg.AttributeSpecificToNoaggRow
    ...
}
```

This might look somehow risky at runtime, but if the caller always passes matching pairs of model/name values to Count() (and I assume it does so), the typecast should be safe.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, these HOLD, ..., OCC methods depends on the "noagg" model attributes, and new methods, depends on "acsi" attributes. All models of stat interface have the same attributes like "date", "id_tree_division", etc.. But also each of them have its own attributes fot specific calculations. So new methods would work only with attributes that exists in new models, and go app would not be compiled unless i would find the solution of theese. With somebodies help, i hope)

Comment: Ah ok... Somehow I already felt that my answer was too easy to solve your problem :-) Fortunately, there seems a way of doing what you need. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, it might work. I hoped to use more object oriented way, and keep all model specific functions inside their own classes, but your way makes me to move all the calculations methods to the stat model. Ihoped to use them like I did with filterData, ClusterData and CountData methods. They have different, model specific logics, but i call them from one place. Just the model , for which i call them can differ. In my first code example there is a code : ```deserializedData.CountDataForChart(string(chart.Name)) ```. It calls this methods by string nsme, from the specific model.

Comment: I think the OOP approach is possible in Go as well, just without the inheritance part. Interfaces define the common behavior, and the structs can provide specific implementations of that interface.
Difficult to explain in a comment, maybe this playground code clarifies what I tried to say... https://play.golang.org/p/DnVsE9keuD

Comment: Some clarifications added, some typos fixed: https://play.golang.org/p/A4A_QmeKRS

Comment: So, you recommend to create the interface for NoaggRow && AcsiRow (in my case), m.b. "StatRow" , & add to this new "row" interface methods for counting data, and make implementations of this methods in each row model. If I'm not mistaken, than the noagg method chartCount might be not modified even. Yes || no ?

Comment: I made a mistake, method should be changed, because it (or they) have to implement interface, and so, the have to be connected to model. So I would try not to send data as parameter, but to use it from model that called for count

Comment: The main problem solved. Thanks a lot! I remembered how live with Go again)

Comment: Great! Good to hear that you were able to find a way of implementing this.

Comment: thanks for your support. Golang is not the main language in my servers ecosystem, but i really love it. Hope that soon all main important functional elements here would be moved to microservices on Go))